# Dojo Clustered cum Stacked Bar

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I want to create a dojo chart with column bars both clustered and stacked. The following link shows a simple image of the type of chart that i need :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3lO44KK40FYYWlQVV84dTMwcjA/edit?usp=sharing

The same thing needs to be achieved using Dojo charts as well. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried both clustered and stacked in one, but looks like it may be possible:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/charting.html
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_stacked.html

Comment: I've checked out both the links. Clustered and Stacked - seperately have tried them, but no luck with combining both of these things.